# Numbering tables with tabular

Tags: tables, numbering

I'm really new to Latex and would need some help with some basic coding: I can't number this table (which I would just be Table 1 right now). `\label{tab:Deactivation}` is not working, if I place it after `\begin{tabular}`. If I place it right before the end vertical lines 1 and 2 get longer(!).
I tried using `\begin{table}` around `{center}` like I've seen done in the wikibook but it seems to push the table to the end of the document, right before the references.

```
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| }
\hline 
Type & Formula & $C_i$  \\ \hline
 &  &  \\  
Series Reaction & $A \rightarrow R  \rightarrow P \downarrow $ & $C_r$ \\ 
&  &  \\ 
Parallel Reaction & $A \rightarrow R $; $ A \rightarrow P \downarrow $ & $C_a$  \\ 
&  &  \\ 
Side-by-side Reaction & $A \rightarrow R $; $ P \rightarrow P \downarrow $ & $C_p$  \\ 
&  &  \\ 
Multiple Mechanisms & $A \rightarrow R \rightarrow P \downarrow $ ; $ A \rightarrow P \downarrow $ & $C_a + C_r$  \\
&  &  \\\hline
\end{tabular}
 \end{center}
```

I know I'm doing something wrong, but what?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\begin{table}...\end{table}` around what you have will make your table a `float` which thus will not necessarily appear at exactly the point where it appears in your code, but at a place TeX feels it fits - look for float placement [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat). Also, what you want is produced by `\caption{Table Description}`, rather than by `\label{..}` which is used for references to the table.

Comment: @greyshade Perfect, I was able to add both the caption and the label for future references. Now I'm just going to have to get into  `float ` to place it where I want, or find out about referencing elements later in the text but I already found a question. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a table or figure should be placed as desired and not float away, it's better to drop the `table` or `figure` environment and use `\captionof{table}{Title}` to generate the legend for the table of figure. This will generate the correct numbering and a `\label{}` command can be used to refer to the entity as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\clearpage

\blindtext

And now for something completely different

\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| }
\hline 
Type & Formula & $C_i$  \\ \hline
 &  &  \\  
Series Reaction & $A \rightarrow R  \rightarrow P \downarrow $ & $C_r$ \\ 
&  &  \\ 
Parallel Reaction & $A \rightarrow R $; $ A \rightarrow P \downarrow $ & $C_a$  \\ 
&  &  \\ 
Side-by-side Reaction & $A \rightarrow R $; $ P \rightarrow P \downarrow $ & $C_p$  \\ 
&  &  \\ 
Multiple Mechanisms & $A \rightarrow R \rightarrow P \downarrow $ ; $ A \rightarrow P \downarrow $ & $C_a + C_r$  \\
&  &  \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{My sophisticated table}\label{sophisticatedtable}
\end{center} 

\blindtext[2]

In table \ref{sophisticatedtable} on page \pageref{sophisticatedtable} we can see ...



\end{document}
```

[image]